# Подсчёт по столбцу без учета повторений значений в этом столбце

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно написать функцию, которая будет считать кол-во решенных задач студента по его id, но при этом исключала повторения.

Пример (id, номер задачи)

```
1, 4
2, 3
2, 3
```

Ответ должен быть такой: `{1 : 1, 2 : 1}` ( то есть студент с id 1 решил 1 задачу, и студент с id 2 тоже решил 1 задачу).

Код, который работает, если номер задачи не повторяется:

```
def solved_tasks(filename):
    answer = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            s_id, t = line.split(',')
            s_id = int(s_id)
            if s_id not in answer:
                answer[s_id] = 0
            answer[s_id] +=1
    return answer
```

А как учесть повторения?

Comment: Что делает этот код, если есть повторения? Он, кстати, нерабочий. Будет ошибка в 6-й строке.

Comment: ничего не будет, он посчитает повторяющуюся задачу за новую

Comment: а в 6 строке, случайно затерялось _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант - в момент обработки хранить, какие именно задачи были решены, а перед выдачей результата удалить эти данные, оставив только число решённых задач

```py
def solved_tasks(filename):
  answer = {}
  with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
      s_id, t = line.split(',')
      s_id = int(s_id)
      if s_id not in answer:
        answer[s_id] = [0, []]
      if t not in answer[s_id][1]:
        answer[s_id][0] += 1
        answer[s_id][1] += [t]
  for key in answer:
    answer[key] = answer[key][0]
  return answer
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать словарь со множествами в качестве значений. Множества автоматически игнорируют повторяющиеся элементы.

Пример:

```
from collections import defaultdict    

def solved_tasks(filename):
    data = defaultdict(set)
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            items = line.split(", ")
            data[int(items[0])].add(int(items[1]))
    return {k:len(v) for k,v in data.items()}
```

результат:

```
In [33]: solved_tasks(r"C:\temp\data2.txt" )
Out[33]: {1: 1, 2: 1}
```